# Mechanism of append function in a python for loop

Tags: python

By definition `List.append(elem)` adds a single element to the end of the list.

however, the result of the codes below does not follow the rule:

```
lista = []

listb = []

for i in "abc":

    lista.append(i)

    listb.append(lista)

print(listb)
```

The result is:

`[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]`

according the rule, the result should be

`[['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]`

why is that? and how to get the second result?

Comment: it *does* ad a single item, every time you are add **the same list**.

Comment: when `lista` is updated so does `listb`

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, but I can never find a good dupe target for these...

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't append ['a'], ['a', 'b'] and ['a', 'b', 'c'] but the reference to lista three times. And lista gets changed so it shows list (a) three times as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending only reference to `listb` to `lista`. To get a desired result, you need to add copy of `listb` to `lista` (in this case is simple `list()` enough):

```
lista = []    
listb = []

for i in "abc":    
    lista.append(i)    
    listb.append(list(lista))

print(listb)
```

Result:

```
[['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy() will do the trick:

```
lista = []

listb = []

for i in "abc":

    lista.append(i)

    listb.append(lista.copy())

print(listb)
```

You were appending the reference of a to b, then manipulating a...

Comment: `copy()` will only work in Python 3.3+. For lower version we can slice it `listb.append(lista[:])`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding the entirety of `lista` to `listb` and not a single element of `lista`.

For every iteration in "abc" you append the entire `lista`.

Answer (score 0):

1. lista and listb are actually references to lists. I will call them variables.
2. Append() is adding things to the value that the variable refers to which is the actual list; furthermore, only you have finished operations to the variable (lista in this case), the actual list will be fixed.
3. So listb.append(lista) actually adds the references into listb and listb will have lista's reference here. Just as mentioned above, the value that listb refers to will be fixed after lista finishes its own operations and that's why listb will have the whole lista instead of part of lista.
4. You can try to reverse the order of two append() operations and it will give you the same answer.

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) for more info on list variables storing by reference and how to achieve the desired behavior

Comment: I see what you said. I didn't write the solution to the desired behaviour. I agree with your link, either copy() or list() can do things; they actually do the deep clone.